# Configuration error for pep8 and flymake for emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I am trying to configure pep8 to ignore E221, E222, and E226 (all related to spacing around operators).  I followed this documentation
https://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.6/intro.html
to generate a .config/pep8 file.  My actual file looks like this:

```
[pep8]
ignore=E123,E133,E221,E222,E226,E241,E242
max-line-length = 100
```

The problem is that flymake crashes and complains that there is a configuration error.
If I remove E226, flymake and pep8 work fine -- although PEP8 now complains about spaces around math operators.
If I remove E221 and E222, flymake and pep8 work fine -- although PEP8 now complains about numbers of spaces.

The point of the configuration was to avoid these warnings.  I don't see how they are logically conflicting and would expect this to work.

My questions are:

1) Is there a reason this type of configuration is not acceptable to PEP8? i.e., why can't I do this?

2) If its a bug, is it a problem of pep8 or flymake?  How to tell?

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Emacs 24.3+1-2ubuntu1
- pep8 1.4.6-1.1build1

Cheers,

--Jim